# Is there a way to get a newer version of the Duo SDK for ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, duosecurity

Currently the only version of the SDK for Duo works with the deprecated v2 of Duo's web SDK. I'm looking for a way to simply get started with bringing Duo's 2FA into my ColdFusion application. I've looked at Duo's guide for upgrading from v2 to v4 and it isn't terribly specific. They seem to no longer be developing the ColdFusion SDK, but I've got a very large legacy ColdFusion application that can't be easily migrated to node or something else at the moment. This is the SDK I've seen so far: https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_coldfusion

Comment: Use the still maintained Java SDK instead. You can use Java libraries within ColdFusion.

Comment: How would I go about that?